# Chaining ajax call in angularJs service in any case (success and fail)

Tags: angularjs

I have this service:

```
app.factory('myService', function ($http, $q){
   return { 
     getItems: function (){ 

       return $q.all([
           $http.get('part1.json').then(function(result){return result}),
           $http.get('par2.json').then(function(result){console.log(result)})
       ])
     }
   } 
})
```

I would like to retrieve the data from two different source, so with this simple service I make asynchronous call. But if one call fail, I will have no result. I need to concatenate result in any case, success or fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using $q.all with promise returned by `then` method rather than `get` method. In this case if you do like this

```
return $q.all([
           $http.get('part1.json').then(function(result){return result},function(error){return [];}),
           $http.get('par2.json').then(function(result){console.log(result)},function(error){return [];})
       ])
       .then(function(result) {//Concatenate result[0],result[1]});
```

This would never fail the result.

Comment: It's the same also with "post" method?

Comment: The actual method does not make a difference `get`, `post`, `save`. This is feature of promise.